# Loop tasks by replacing one unique filename part by another

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am new to R and have just written a code, which works fine. I would like to loop this so that it also applies to the other identical 41 data.frames.

The inputfiles are called "weatherdata.. + **UNIQUE NUMBER**", the output files I would like to call "df + UNIQUE NUMBER".

The code I have written applies now only to the file weatherdata..**5341**. I could just press CTRL + F and replace all 5341 and run which is easy to do. But could I also do this with some sort of loop? or do you have a nice tutorial for me that could teach me how to do this? I have seen a tutorial with the for-loop but I couldn't figure out how to apply it for my code.
A small part of the code is provided below! I think that if the loop works on the code given below it will also work for the rest of the code. All help appreciated! :)

```
#List of part of the datafiles just 4 out of 42 files
list.dat <- list(weatherdata..5341,weatherdata..5344, weatherdata..5347, 
                 weatherdata..5350)

# add colum with date(month) as a decimal number
weatherdata..5341$Month <- format( as.Date(weatherdata..5341$Date) , "%m")

# convert to date if not already
weatherdata..5341$Date <- as.Date(weatherdata..5341$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")

#Try rename columns
colnames(weatherdata..5341)[colnames(weatherdata..5341)=="Max.Temperature"] <- "TMPMX"

    # store as a vector
v1 <- unlist(Tot1)

  # store in outputfile dataframe
Df5341<- as.data.frame.list(v1)
```

Comment: You could improve your question. Imho a good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data, and reproducible code - all copy-paste-run'able. The poster also should throw off any ballast (=99% here?). So abstract from your problem, minimize your ex. data set & code while retaining full reproducibility, focus on the actual problem and make sure there's a question that stands out. Here, it looks like you want to replace some characters in some filenames. So, provide a few filenames using e.g. `dput(myfilenames[1:5])` and also show, what you want them to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of all the dataframes and then use `sapply` to loop through each one of them. Here is a sample code :

```
> v1 <- list(data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c('a', 'b')), data.frame(x = c(3,4), y = c('c', 'd')))
> v1
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b

[[2]]
  x y
1 3 c
2 4 d

> sapply(v1 , function(x){(x$x <- x$x/4)})
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.25 0.75
[2,] 0.50 1.00
```

Then you can replace content inside the function. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't get how I should insert my dataframes into your formula. I tried it the following way, but that gave an error: " unexpected ," and sometimes also gives: " unexpected }"
 v1 <- list(data.frame(weatherdata..5341,weatherdata..5344, weatherdata..5347, weatherdata..5350))
             sapply(v1 , function(x){(x$Month <- format( as.Date(x$Date) , "%m"), (x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")})

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
## Assuming that your files are CSV files and are alone in the folder 

Fnames <- list.files() # this pulls the names of all the files 
                       # in your working directory
Data <- lapply(Fnames, read.csv)
for( i in 1:length(Data)){
  # Put your code in here, replacing the Df names with Data[[i]]
  # for example:

  # add colum with date(month) as a decimal number
  Data[[i]]$Month <- format( as.Date(Data[[i]]$Date) , "%m")

  # convert to date if not already
  Data[[i]]$Date <- as.Date(Data[[i]]$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")

  #Try rename columns
  colnames(Data[[i]])[colnames(Data[[i]])=="Max.Temperature"] <- "TMPMX"

  # And so on..
}
```